# Split a string between two specific characters in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with more than 2000 rows and each row appears as below. I've pasted 2 rows :

```
ROW 1 CA WAAE JOB: "abc_def__ghijkl_mnop_qrst_c" JOBSET: "abc_def__ghijkl_mnop_qrst_b"   
ROW 2 CA WAAE JOB: "mon_bus_xyz_ff_kkkkk_abcdef_uvwx_b" JOBSET:"mon_bus_xyz_ff_kkkkk_abcdef_uvwx_b"
```

I want to copy the data present between the first set of `""` i.e `abc_def__ghijkl_mnop_qrst_c` and `mon_bus_xyz_ff_kkkkk_abcdef_uvwx_b` and pasted them into another column. Would it be possible to do this?

Comment: Do you NEED it in formula ? There is an option `Text to Columns` to do that in 5 sec !

Comment: I would need a formula if possible. I tried Mid in the below manner but i dont think it will work in the long run

=MID(Z2,15,FIND(">",Z2,1)-15)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the entry is in A1 then use:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("""",A1,1)+1,9999),FIND("""",MID(A1,FIND("""",A1,1)+1,9999))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your cell is A1, following formula will take 2 strings between (") and put them into one cell separated with "-".

`=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("""",A1)),""" JOBSET: """," - "),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("""",A1)),""" JOBSET: """," - "))-1)`

Explanation:

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("""",A1))` - Remove all characters from left until first (") character.
`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,""" JOBSET: """," - ")` - Substitute "JOBSET:" with a dash charachter "-".
`=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)` - Drop the last (") character.

Nesting all into one formula is given above. Output:

`abc_def__ghijkl_mnop_qrst_c - abc_def__ghijkl_mnop_qrst_b`